# Are "what are the advantages of" questions no longer welcome on SO?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, community-wiki

I just asked this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236294/what-can-you-do-in-c-cli-that-you-fundamentally-cannot-do-in-c

I knew in the back of my mind that it would likely be closed as not constructive, as I see many questions like this being closed recently. It was, and I am not even going to vote to re-open my question, but it raises a bunch of questions for me about what is considered welcome on SO.

Questions like this used to be welcome on the site and generate constructive answers. For example:

[What can you do in MSIL that you cannot do in C# or VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541936/what-can-you-do-in-msil-that-you-cannot-do-in-c-sharp-or-vb-net)

Are there policy changes that mean questions like this are no longer welcome? Why are they not welcome when they appear to generate quality site content?

Comment: As I see it, discussions of any kind are not welcome, and it's not new - it's just that as the volume of question grow, the community is more strict about those things.

Comment: `Why are they not welcome when they appear to generate quality site content?` They _don't_ generate quality content, the MSIL question is one of the _very few_ exceptions.

Answer (score 15):

These questions have been 'not constructive' for quite a while, except perhaps if you focus one to a very specific, very practical, very concrete situation.

Comment: Precisely. _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**._

Comment: And one of the problems with quoting the rare not-constructive question that generates some quality content is that is overlooks the countless other (deleted) examples that did not do so.